# Notification Action Intent not fired

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Clicking on the notification action does not fire run the BroadcastReceiver

```java
Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(c, NotificationBroadcast.class);
cancelIntent.setAction(CANCEL_UPLOAD);
cancelIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST, new Request(request));
//c is ApplicationContext
PendingIntent cancel = getBroadcast(c,1, cancelIntent,
                FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

nb.addAction(R.drawable.close, c.getString(R.string.cancel), cancel);
```

NotificationBroadcast implementation

```java
public class AppNotification {
   public static class NotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Request cancel = cancelRequest((Request) intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST));
            if (CANCEL_UPLOAD.equals(intent.getAction()))
                cancel.clearFlag(FLAG_REQUEST);
            updateRequest(context, cancel);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect NotificationBroadcast#onReceive to be called when the notification action is clicked but it is not being called;

Comment: Is `NotificationBroadcast` registered in your manifest? If so, how? Do you see any messages in Logcat when you click the action?

Comment: No, NotificationBroadcast  is not registered since I am using explicit intent.

Answer (score 0):

> NotificationBroadcast is not registered since I am using explicit intent

That does not matter. All receivers need to be registered, either via the manifest or via a `registerReceiver()` call on a `Context`. In your case, since you are using a `PendingIntent` for a notification action, you need to use the manifest option.

Your `<receiver>` in the manifest does not need to have an `<intent-filter>`, since you are using a explicit broadcast. However, the `<receiver>` element must still be there.

Also, since you elected to have your receiver be a `static` class,  your `android:name` for your `<receiver>` needs to take that into account.

Comment: I registered NotificationBroadcast in manifest and it is working now. Thank you